# Wrapping long text without white space inside of a div

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with wrapping text. I am generating some hexencoding encryption and the output is too long like:

> 827938828ey823876te37257e5t328er6367r5erd663275e65r532r6s3624e5645376er563rdr753624e544341763r567r4e56r326r5632r65sr32dr32udr56r634r57rd63725

and it continues. When I put it inside a `div`, it won't wrap it even if I assign a specific width, because they are all together. I want it to continue from the next line if the `div` is not wide enough for one line.

How can I do that?

Comment: apperently stackoverflow.com is implementing what I need here. it continues from second line. when I look at this page's source code, I see the following for post-text: width: 660px;
font-size: 107%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
line-height: 130%;

Answer (score 67, accepted):

<strike>You can't wrap that text as it's unbroken without any spaces. You need a JavaScript or server side solution which splits the string after a few characters.</strike>

**EDIT**

You need to add this property in CSS.

`word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 18):

I have found something strange here about `word-wrap` only works with `width` property of CSS properly.

```css
#ONLYwidth {
  width: 200px;
}

#wordwrapWITHOUTWidth {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#wordwrapWITHWidth {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<b>This is the example of word-wrap only using width property</b>
<p id="ONLYwidth">827938828ey823876te37257e5t328er6367r5erd663275e65r532r6s3624e5645376er563rdr753624e544341763r567r4e56r326r5632r65sr32dr32udr56r634r57rd63725</p>
<br/>
<b>This is the example of word-wrap without width property</b>
<p id="wordwrapWITHOUTWidth">827938828ey823876te37257e5t328er6367r5erd663275e65r532r6s3624e5645376er563rdr753624e544341763r567r4e56r326r5632r65sr32dr32udr56r634r57rd63725</p>
<br/>
<b>This is the example of word-wrap with width property</b>
<p id="wordwrapWITHWidth">827938828ey823876te37257e5t328er6367r5erd663275e65r532r6s3624e5645376er563rdr753624e544341763r567r4e56r326r5632r65sr32dr32udr56r634r57rd63725</p>
```

Here is a working demo that I have prepared about it. http://jsfiddle.net/Hss5g/2/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following

```
p{word-break: break-all;}

        <p>LoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolorLoremipsumdolor</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

is what worked for me for `<span>` and `<div>`.