# How to make text inside a div multiline?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wrapping the text inside div - css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120313/wrapping-the-text-inside-div-css)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTFK2/2/

*HTML:*

```
<div id="ChannelDescription">ThisIsAVeryLongTextWithoutAnySpacesLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmedLoremIpsumDolorSitAmed</div>​
```

*CSS:*

```
#ChannelDescription {
  width:560px;
  color:Gray;
  white-space:normal;
  font-size:14px;
}​
```

NOTE: I cannot change the width to any other value. Neither can I use break points. I am looking for a pure CSS2 solution.

Comment: It's work till IE7 check this http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Comment: Check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div

Comment: Yes its was what I was looking for, was in the belief that CSS3 compatibility is fairly limited in browsers, but his answer worked. thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`word-wrap: break-word;` will solve the problem.

Comment: `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: white-space: pre-wrap;

Comment: This will not work if width is 100%

Comment: @RenilBabu : Thanks , "white-space: pre-wrap;" worked for me.

Comment: also don't forget to remove `display: flex;` from text div